# How to go to previous ViewController automatically with a timer delay

Tags: swift

I need to go to previous ViewController (VC1) automatically after 10 seconds of showing VC2. How can I code this using xcode10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this inside `viewDidLoad` of the second vc

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: false) { (t) in
    t.invalidate()
    // dismiss if you present it
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
    // or with navigation
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You can use the second view as a Popup and put a function make the VC2 dismiss automatically in viewDidAppear.